# Taking values from stdin and storing those in linked list nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

Yesterday after I did a stupid approach, I think I am on a good way right now. The thing I wanna program is that I am getting n values from the user and I am trying to store every value into a linked list node which has to be sorted after every input.

So it means:

Input:
5 1 9

Output:
1 5 9

Input:
2 3

Output:
1 2 3 5 9

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void printList(node* n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", n->val);
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void push(node * head, int val) {
    node * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

/* now we can add a new variable */
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}

int main() {
    char input[20];
    char* ptr;
    node* head = NULL;
    head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    do {
        printf("Eingabe:");
        fgets(input,20,stdin);
        ptr = strtok(input," ");

        while(ptr!=NULL){
            int val = atoi(ptr);
            push(head,val);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        printList(head);
    }
    while(*input != '0');

    return 0;
}
```

Edited my code, node creation is working , but when I input 5 1 9 , it outputs 0 5 1 9 where is that 0 coming from?

Comment: So what's the problem? And please format your code properly. 50% empty lines is not a good thing.

Comment: @klutt I dont know where to go from here, I tried to figure it out but I didnt do any progress, formatted it, sorry.

Comment: I formatted it for you. But the question is still, what is the problem? Does it work? If not, how does it not work? Please read [ask].

Comment: It does not work, I am trying to figure out how to create new nodes, with the value passed to the create node function

Comment: Well, there are tons of examples out there for how to implement linked lists. Just pick one. Here is one: https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

Comment: Okay that link helped me a lot, one more small problem it outputs what I inputted but with a 0 in front of it, how is that coming? WIll edit my code.

Comment: No offence, but I have already fixed the indentation once for your code...

Comment: @klutt I am sorry, I am not so onm point with this code indenting

Comment: No, worries, but as I said. Read [ask]. If you just tried some code you found, then it's not acceptable to post a question about it within a few minutes. You should do your research first. Now is a good time to learn how to debug. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0 is the `value` of your `head`.

When you create the first node you add it as the `next` of the head, this means that by having as input 5 1 9 your linked list will be:

```
head -> 5 -> 1 -> 9
```

When you print you don't just print the values of the nodes you have created but also the value of the head, since the value was never initialized and in the `struct` it's an `int` your compiler intializes it to 0 automatically (this depends on the compiler implementation so it's always better to initialize it).

If you don't want that 0 in the front you have a couple of options:

1. assign to `head->value` the first number that you input
2. call the printList as `printList(head->node)`
3. change your linked list implementation to not have the head hold a value
4. change printList to:

   ```
   void printList(node* n) {
        n = n->next;
        while (n != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", n->val);
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach could be (pseudo-code):

```
[START]
Read new line from the STDIN;
While there are new values:
  Read new value;
      Add it on new node (easier adding on top of the list);
Sort the list;
Print the list;
Loop to [START]
```

In your code you are missing the "sort the list" phase.

Easier if you add a swap function and try one of sorting algorithm on your choice

Comment: I know that the pseudo code should look like this but I am new to C and I cant figure out how to create the nodes with the value, I need help wtih that, I wanna implement the sorting later for now, I am jsut looking to create the nodes with the vales and then to print the whole list

Comment: To add a new node you should dynamically  allocate a chunk of memory, cast it then insert in the list.
As already suggested, please read how to implement some linked list, that is a well-known topic in C programming.

Comment: Got it done,edited my code, got one more small problem , when I input 5 1 9 , it outputs 0 5 1 9 , where is that 0 coming from?

Comment: You are using 0 as value to recognize that there are no more numbers to read. So you should not push any value if the input is equal to 0

Comment: The 0 appears without inputting a 0

Comment: input: 5 1 9
output: 0 5 1 9     where is that 0 in front of the 5 coming from, couldnt figure that out

Comment: You are using the head as the first element of the list.
Try adding  head->val = 4; just after the head malloc.

The head should be a pointer to the first element of the list if that exist (pointer to pointer), not an actual element of the list.